# Can't create twilio media templates

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I've been trying to use this link to create a template that holds a file:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/content-api/twilio-media

when i try to create the same template as the example i get this error:

```
{"code": 20404, "message": "The requested resource /Content was not found", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404", "status": 404}
```

i made sure my account's details that i was passing to the api were correct but still the error shows

i need the template to be created when i make the request using the api provided

Answer (score 0):

Is your account allowed to use the Content API?! Before using the Content API, you need to fill out a form for Twilio Team to allow it to your account. You can see it on the init of [this page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/content-api/create-and-send-your-first-content-api-template).

When your account is allowed to use the API you will be able to create Content Templates by API.

I hope that it can help you! :D